# asynchronisme problem to consum an existing api

Tags: typescript, rest, api, async-await

I'm actually doing a webApp using an existing Api : PokéAPI
The thing is, i want to get all pokemons names and print them in a first time. And it works !! but ... not in order. What i want is to print the liste of pokemon ordered by id ( first is bulbasaur second ivysaure etc) and here sometimes ulbasaur is the fifth of the list etc. I could resolve it i think with async and awaits seeking on internet but i can't make it work.

Already tried the async await solution but certainly in a wrong way. I d'ont know where to use them and when and how

===data.service.ts===

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPokemons(id) {
    return this.http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + id +'/')
   }
}
```

===home.component.ts===

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons: any = [];

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    for(var i=1; i<152; i++){
      await this.data.getPokemons(i).subscribe(data => {
        this.pokemons.push(data)
    })}

   console.log(this.pokemons)
  }

}
```

===home.component.html===

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>

<ul *ngIf="pokemons">
  <li *ngFor="let u of pokemons">
      {{u.name}}
  </li>

</ul>
```

Expected : bulbasaur ivysaur venusaur
Actual : charmender beedrill ivysaur (random order)

EDIT :
So i checked your solution and maybe i didn't understood but i did this :

ngOnInit() {

```
forkJoin(
  [...Array(151)].map((_, i) => this.data.getPokemons(i + 1))
)
.subscribe(data => {
  this.pokemons = data;
  console.log(this.pokemons)
});
}
```

and got this error on the console.log : ERROR TypeError: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

I supposed the problem is with the "_" in the map function, seek on internet and didn't find something like this. We agree i dont need to write the loadAllAtOnce function, it was just an example ? And i hope i'm not annoying you with my questions but what is the meaning of [...Array(151)].map ? (what is the "...")

EDIT : Something is very strange. I created a new component to be in my nav bar ont the top of my site because my list was in the Home component and i wanted to put it in an other not the home page. and just to test i let the list also in the home component.
When i switch from one component to the other (home to pokedex or pokedex to home) my list is in the good order like i want. but when i refresh the same component the list is no more in the good order. I don't understand why but maybe this precision can help you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make all the calls at once and then wait for all of them to complete with **forkJoin**. It will give you the responses in an array in the same order as the array of observables you give to the **forkJoin** function.

It looks something like this:

```js
loadAllAtOnce(values: number[]) {
  return forkJoin(
    values.map(x => of (x).pipe(delay(x)))
  ).pipe(
    tap(values => {
      console.log(values);

    })
  );
}
```

You can see a fully working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-vs-merge).

In your case the code would look something like this:

```js
forkJoin(
    Array(151) // make an empty array with length 152
      .fill(0) // fill it with zeros
      .map((_, i) => this.data.getPockemons(i + 1)) // _ means ignore the parameter
  )
  .subscribe(pockemons => {
    this.pockemons = pockemons;
    console.log(this.pokemons)
  });
```

You can find an example of this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-forkjoin).

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it later and tell youif its working ! thanks again for your time :)

Comment: I edited my post, if you can help me :) thanks again

Comment: hey, it looks like there is an issue with using `map` on an array that is not filled for some reason. I updated the answer to just fill the array with zeros. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works :) thank you again for your time, is there a way to pass the subject to solved ? And i have some questions about web dev and like you seem to know this better than me is there somewhere we can talk ? Thanks again sorry for my english if i made mistakes and goodbye :)

Comment: you should have a checkmark on the answer, near the score. As for chatting, you can find me here. https://discord.gg/SpW9jfP